# Print strings with regex rules

Tags: regex

i need regex to print strings by these rules:

1. letters a-f (lower case)
2. numbers 0-9
3. letter can't be after letter (forms like: 'aa' ,'bc', 'db')
4. string length will be exactly 20.

I have tried to play with some regex expressions but with no luck

Answer (score 1):

You may use a negative preceding context for letter characters:

```
/^(?:[0-9]|(?<![a-f])[a-f]){20}$/
```